# How can i check for only one occurence only of each provided symbol?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a provided array of symbols, which can be different. For instance, like this - ['@']. One occurrence of each symbol is a mandatory. But in a string there can be only one of each provided sign.

Now I do like this:

```
const regex = new RegExp(`^\\w+[${validatedSymbols.join()}]\\w+$`);
```

But it also returns an error on signs like '=' and so on. For example:

```
/^\w+[@]\w+$/.test('string@=string')  // false
```

So, the result I expect:

- 'string@string' - ok
- 'string@@string - not ok

Comment: Could you provide more info? The two provided example strings match your criteria. `"string@string".match(regex) //=> match` and `"string@@string".match(regex)//=> null` assuming `validatedSymbols` is `["@"]`. *"But it also returns an error on signs like '=' and so on."* is very vague. What is the error? where in your code is the `=`?

Comment: the problem is that there are also an error on signs which weren't provided( @3limin4t0r

Answer (score -1):

Using a complex regex is most likely not the best solution. I think you would be better of creating a validation function.

In this function you can find all occurrence of the provided `symbols` in `string`. Then return `false` if no occurrences are found, or if the list of occurrences contains duplicate entries.

```js
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#escaping
const escapeRegExp = (string) => string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');

function validate(string, symbols) {
  if (symbols.length == 0) {
    throw new Error("at least one symbol must be provided in the symbols array");
  }

  const symbolRegex = new RegExp(symbols.map(escapeRegExp).join("|"), "g");
  const symbolsInString = string.match(symbolRegex); // <- null if no match
  // string must at least contain 1 occurrence of any symbol
  if (!symbolsInString) return false;

  // symbols may only occur once
  const hasDuplicateSymbols = symbolsInString.length != new Set(symbolsInString).size;
  return !hasDuplicateSymbols;
}


const validatedSymbols = ["@", "="];
const strings = [
  "string!*string", // invalid (doesn't have "@" nor "=")
  "string@!string", // valid
  "string@=string", // valid
  "string@@string", // invalid (max 1 occurance per symbol)
];

console.log("validatedSymbols", "=", JSON.stringify(validatedSymbols));
for (const string of strings) {
  const isValid = validate(string, validatedSymbols);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(string), "//=>", isValid);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for the following:

```
const regex = new RegExp(`^\\w+[${validatedSymbols.join()}]?\\w+$`);
```

The question mark means 1 or 0 of the previous group.

You might also need to escape the symbols in `validatedSymbols` as some symbols have a different meaning in regex

Edit:

For mandatory symbols it would be easier to add a group per symbol:

```
^\w+(@\w*){1}(#\w*){1}\w+$
```

Where the group is:

```
(@\w*){1}
```

Comment: "*One occurrence of each symbol is a mandatory*"

Comment: I think you would need to add a group per symbol then example: `^\w+(@\w*){1}(#\w*){1}\w+$` where the group is `(@\w*){1}`